# wp.data.select('meta') property undefined with Gutenberg for WordPress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I use Gutenberg with WordPress and I would like to check some fields before the user publish his post.

I would like to check if the `featured image`, the `title` and a simple `text field` in a meta-box are not empty.

If a field is empty a notification is displayed and I locked the "Publish" button.

For the moment all works fine with the `featured image` and the `title`. But when I'm trying to check is the text field in the meta-box is empty I got errors :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_myprefix_text_metafield' of undefined
```

I created my meta-box with a text field like that :

```
import { __ } from '@wordpress/i18n';
import { useSelect, useDispatch } from '@wordpress/data';
import { registerPlugin } from '@wordpress/plugins';
import { PluginDocumentSettingPanel } from '@wordpress/edit-post';
import { TextControl } from '@wordpress/components';

const TextController = (props) => {
    const meta = useSelect(
        (select) =>
        select('core/editor').getEditedPostAttribute('meta')['_myprefix_text_metafield']
    );
    const { editPost } = useDispatch('core/editor');
    return (
        <TextControl
        label={__("Text Meta", "textdomain")}
        value={meta}
        onChange={(value) => editPost({ meta: { _myprefix_text_metafield: value } })}
        />
    );
};

const PluginDocumentSettingPanelDemo = () => (
    <PluginDocumentSettingPanel name="text-presentation" title="Texte de présentation" className="custom-panel custom-panel-presentation" icon=" ">
        <TextController />
    </PluginDocumentSettingPanel>
);

registerPlugin('plugin-document-setting-panel-demo', {
    render: PluginDocumentSettingPanelDemo
});
```

And to check if all fields are not empty :

```
const locks = [];

function lock( lockIt, handle, message ) {
    if ( lockIt ) {
        if ( ! locks[ handle ] ) {
            locks[ handle ] = true;
            wp.data.dispatch( 'core/editor' ).lockPostSaving( handle );
            wp.data.dispatch( 'core/notices' ).createNotice(
                'error',
                message,
                { id: handle, isDismissible: false }
            );
        }
    } else if ( locks[ handle ] ) {
        locks[ handle ] = false;
        wp.data.dispatch( 'core/editor' ).unlockPostSaving( handle );
        wp.data.dispatch( 'core/notices' ).removeNotice( handle );
    }
}

wp.data.subscribe( () => {
    // get presentation
    const textPresentation = wp.data.select( 'core/editor' ).getEditedPostAttribute('meta')['_myprefix_text_metafield'];

    // Lock the post if the presentation is empty.
    lock(
        ! textPresentation,
        'presentation-lock',
        'Please add a presentation text',
    );

    // get the current title
    const postTitle = wp.data.select( 'core/editor' ).getEditedPostAttribute( 'title' );

    // Lock the post if the title is empty.
    lock(
        ! postTitle,
        'title-lock',
        'Please add a title',
    );


    // get the Featured Image
    const featuredImage = wp.data.select( 'core/editor' ).getEditedPostAttribute( 'featured_media' );

    // Lock post if there is no Featured Image selected
    lock(
        featuredImage === 0,
        'featured-image-lock',
        'Please add a featured image',
    );

});
```

When I write this in the console :

`wp.data.select( 'core/editor' ).getEditedPostAttribute('meta')['_myprefix_text_metafield'];`

The value returned well the value of my text field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That could happen when the XHR/AJAX request that fetches post data from the REST API hasn't been fully resolved, so you can't simply access the metadata like that. You need to ensure that `getEditedPostAttribute('meta')` actually returns an object and only then access the `_myprefix_text_metafield` property.

So try with this instead:

```js
const textPresentation = wp.data.select( 'core/editor' ) // wrapped for brevity
    .getEditedPostAttribute( 'meta' )?._myprefix_text_metafield;

// Lock the post if the presentation is empty.
lock(
    undefined !== textPresentation && ! textPresentation,
    'presentation-lock',
    'Please add a presentation text'
);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. That's works fine. In `lock` function you tested at the beggining if `textPresentation ` is `undefiend`, and when the page is completely loaded if `textPresentation ` is not empty ? 

What does "?" means in `wp.data.select( 'core/editor' ).getEditedPostAttribute( 'meta' )?.myprefix_text_metafield`

Comment: It's called [optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining). And equivalent code without using that, is 1) `const meta = wp.data.select( 'core/editor' ).getEditedPostAttribute( 'meta' ) || {};` and 2) `undefined !== meta._myprefix_text_metafield && ! meta._myprefix_text_metafield`